# How can i fix the css stylelint errors caused by sass / scss?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, stylelint, scss-lint

I am using Sass(scss) as the css pre-processor for my project. But when i run `stylelint` for the `.css` files compiled by sass, it returns very many errors which you cant fix directly in the `.css` files because these files are compiled by sass. Anything you change will be lost after sass recompiles the css files.

I have used various sass linting options like `sass-lint` and `sass-lint-auto-fix` but these options, though helpful, have not fixed the problems in the `.css` files.

`stylelint` also keeps flagging the various sass @-rules like `@mixin` and `@include` as unexpected and unknown at-rules.

Any suggestions or thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: But what's the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I run stylelint for the `.css` files compiled by sass, it returns very many errors which you cant fix directly in the `.css`

The linter supports CSS-like syntaxes like SCSS, Sass, Less and SugarSS, as well as extracting embedded styles from HTML, markdown and CSS-in-JS object & template literals.

You should run stylelint on your SCSS source code files, *not* your compiled CSS files:

```
stylelint "**/*.scss"
```

> stylelint also keeps flagging the various sass @-rules like @mixin and @include as unexpected and unknown at-rules.

The rules built into stylelint are geared towards standard CSS. The `@mixin` and `@includes` at-rules are non-standard as they are part of SCSS and not CSS, so they are flagged as unknown. However, the [stylelint-scss plugin pack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-scss) contains rules specific to SCSS and SCSS-like syntax. You can use it by [extending](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#extends) the [stylelint-config-recommended-scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-recommended-scss) sharable config in your [`.stylelintrc.json` configuration file](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure):

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-recommended-scss"],
  "rules": {}
}
```